# How to consume an Observable multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I am new to Angular and RxJS. I wonder what is the best/correct way to consume a value from an `Observable` multiple times.

My setup:
I have a component which calls a service which uses a REST service.
After the server returns the result I want to

- use this result in the service at hand
- AND return the result to the component.

---

```
// foo.component.ts

onEvent() {
    this.fooService.foo()
        .subscribe((data: FooStatus) => doSomething());
}

// foo.service.ts

private lastResult: FooStatus;

constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
}

foo(): Observable<FooResult> {
    return this.http.get('/foo')
        .map((data: FooStatus) => {
            this.lastResult = data; // use the data...
            return data;            // ... and simply pass it through
        });
}
```

Using `subscribe()` multiple times will not work because the request would be send multiple times. This is wrong.

At the moment I use `map()` to intercept the result. But I am not comfortable with this because I introduce a side effect. Seems like a code smell to me.

I experimented with

```
foo(onSuccess: (result: FooResult) => void, onFailure: () => void): void {
    ...
}
```

but this looks even worse, I loose the `Observable` magic. And I do not want to have to write these callbacks in every service method myself.

As another way I considered the call to `subscribe()` in the service and then to create a fresh `Observable` I then can return to the component. But I could not get it work... seemed to complicated, too.

Is there a more elegant solution?
Is there a helpful method on `Observable` I did miss?

Comment: Have you tried using publishReplay?

Comment: I have replicated this same issue in my system and made it work, look at my answer below and let me know if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, and the answer will depend on your usage.

This codepen https://codepen.io/mikkel/pen/EowxjK?editors=0011

```
// interval observer
// click streams from 3 buttons
console.clear()
const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')
const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop')
const resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset')

const start$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(startButton, 'click')
const stop$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(stopButton, 'click')
const reset$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(resetButton, 'click')

const minutes = document.querySelector('#minutes')
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds')
const milliseconds = document.querySelector('#milliseconds')

const toTime = (time) => ({
  milliseconds: Math.floor(time % 100),
  seconds: Math.floor((time/100) % 60),
  minutes: Math.floor(time / 6000)
})

const pad = (number) => number <= 9 ? ('0' + number) : number.toString()

const render = (time) => {
  minutes.innerHTML = pad(time.minutes)
  seconds.innerHTML = pad(time.seconds)
  milliseconds.innerHTML = pad(time.milliseconds)
}

const interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(10)

const stopOrReset$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    stop$,
    reset$
)

const pausible$ = interval$
   .takeUntil(stopOrReset$)
const init = 0   
const inc = acc => acc+1
const reset = acc => init

const incOrReset$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    pausible$.mapTo(inc),
    reset$.mapTo(reset)
)

app$ = start$
      .switchMapTo(incOrReset$)
      .startWith(init)
      .scan((acc, currFunc) => currFunc(acc))
      .map(toTime)
      .subscribe(val => render(val))
```

You will notice that the reset$ observable is used in two other observables, `incOrReset$` and `stopOrReset$`

You can also introduce a `.multicast()` operator, which will explicitly allow you to subscribe multiple times. See description here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [share](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md), it allows you to share a single subscription to the underlying source. You could do something like the following (it's not tested, but should give you the idea):

```
private lastResult: FooStatus;
private fooObs: Observable<FooStatus>;
constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    this.fooObs =  this.http.get('/foo').share();
    this.fooObs.subscribe(((data: FooStatus) => this.lastResult = data);
}

foo(): Observable<FooResult> {
    return this.fooObs.map(toFooResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @Mikkel in his answer that approach is cool however you can make use of following methods from Observable and achieve this.

these important methods are publishReplay and refCount,

use them as below,

```
private lastResult: FooStatus;
private myCachedObservable : Observble<FooResult> = null;

constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
}

foo(): Observable<FooResult> {

    if(!myCachedObservable){
       this.myCachedObservable = this.http.get('/foo')
        .map((data: FooStatus) => {
            this.lastResult = data; // use the data...
            return data;            // ... and simply pass it through
        })
       .publishReplay(1)
       .refCount();
       return this.myObsResponse;
    } else{
    return this.myObsResponse;
    }
}
```

Now in your component simply subscribe the observable returned from your method as above and notice the network request, you will see only one network request being made for this http call.